# Seamlessly deal with authorization token expiration in client app

Tags: ios, api, authentication

Say I'm developing an Evernote or YouTube client, and after the user logs in, the app gets an authorization token from the API server.

Then I use this token to interact with the server until, sometime later, the token expires.

The key is, I don't know if this token is expired until the server returns an error with a message like 'token expired'. Then I have to fetch a new token. Maybe it occurs while the user is posting a message.

So what is an elegant way to deal with this scenario? I want to combine fetching a new token with continuing the last request, so that the user just feels it works as usual.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which flow you're using.  But in general, if you are able to refresh the auth token (via refresh token) without redirecting the user for credentials again, you should do it seamlessly.

Also, you should know exactly when a token is going to expire.  If you're coding against an OAuth 2 implementation, the auth token response should give you an 'expires_in' field as a time span telling you exactly how long the token will expire after it was issued to you.

Comment: yes, auth token does have `expires_in` field, but our server dev said it is not so accurate :(

Comment: yea, it should be used as a reference with a small margin of error.  The field is filled on their servers when the token is generated and does not take into account the time it takes the token to reach your client/application over the net :-)  You can try to compensate by using the time your request was sent rather than the time the response is received. But It is good practice to always handle token expiration errors just in case.  Anyway, you can preempt the error by refreshing your token at a fixed time before the token expires.  That way you can save your client a call.